# Don't submit time past 11:59 pm

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that creates a lesson with a date and time. I currently have validators to ensure that past dates can't be used, which are working perfectly. However, I am having trouble visualising how a validator that makes sure the time entered isn't past 11:59 pm would work. I inlucded a snippet of what I am trying to achieve (I know it doesn't work the way it is layed out, it is just there to provide context). I would appreaciate any help with this.

forms.py

```
def validate_date1(value):
    if value < timezone.now():
        raise ValidationError('Date cannot be in the past')

def validate_date2(value):
    if value < timezone.now():
        raise ValidationError('Date cannot be in the past')

def present_date1(value):
    if value > '11:59 pm':
        raise ValidationError('Time cannot be past 11:59 pm')

def present_date2(value):
    if value > '11:59 pm':
        raise ValidationError('Time cannot be past 11:59 pm')

class LessonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lesson_instrument = forms.ChoiceField(choices=instrument_list, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'required' : 'True'}))
    lesson_datetime_start = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute am/pm'}), validators=[validate_date1, present_date1])
    lesson_datetime_end = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'], required=False, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD Hour:Minute am/pm'}), validators=[validate_date2, present_date2])
    lesson_weekly = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Comment: Your start and end timestamps are `DateTimeField`s not `TimeField`s, so it's not clear what a validator would have to do with your requirement that the time cannot be passed 11:59pm. Can it be 00:01 am, which is before 11:59pm? Or do you really just want to exclude 1 minute of time each day, between 11:59pm and midnight?

Comment: @dirkgroten What I am basically trying to accomplish is I just don't want someone to create something like 2019-05-04 10:00 am - 2019-05-04 12:00 am, as that would not make sense

Answer (score 2):

The validators for a `DateTimeField` will get a `datetime.datetime` object, not a string.

Here we extract the time component out of the datetime and compare it to our constant last possible time.

```py
import datetime

LAST_POSSIBLE_TIME = datetime.time(23, 59)

def validate_time(value):
    if value.time() > LAST_POSSIBLE_TIME:
        raise ValidationError('Time cannot be past 11:59 pm')
```

Comment: Times after 11:59 somehow still pass. Is it because I have both import datetime, and from datetime import datetime

Comment: you can't have `import datetime` followed by `from datetime import datetime`. The second import will define what is `datetime`. Only `import datetime` and replace the other instances where you use a `datetime` object with `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: Also this validation will still allow an interval such as 2019-05-04 11:00pm - 2019-05-05 00:01am.

Answer (score 1):

So, the input date cannot be in the past and it cannot be after `23:59`, so basically it needs to be within the rest of the present day.

How about:

```py
import pytz

def date_is_not_past(dt):
    if dt < datetime.now(pytz.UTC):
        raise ValidationError('Date cannot be in the past')

def date_is_today(dt):
    if dt.date() != datetime.now(pytz.UTC).date():
        raise ValidationError('Date needs to be today')
```

Comment: I get the error can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: Also the date can be in the future I just don't want someone to create something like 2019-05-04 10:00 am - 2019-05-04 12:00 am, as that would not make sense.

Comment: @Shoukran Try now. Just keep in mind that the provided dates need to be on UTC. If another timezone is required, you can change the argument on `datetime.now`, e.g. `datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))`

Comment: @Shoukran So how about just validating that the start date is earlier than the end date? (In your case, the start date `2019-05-04 10:00 am` is later/greater than the end date `2019-05-04 12:00 am`, which would be invalid)

Answer (score 0):

You want to validate `lesson_datetime_start` and `lesson_datetime_end` together, not separately. Just checking that the time isn't greater than 11:59pm doesn't cut it, since that would make 2019-05-04 11:00pm - 2019-05-05 12:00am invalid even though it's a correct one hour interval starting at 11pm.

To do that, add a `clean()` method to your form:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    if self.cleaned_data.get('lesson_datetime_start') \
            and self.cleaned_data.get('lesson_datetime_end') \
            and self.cleaned_data['lesson_datetime_start'] >= self.cleaned_data['lesson_datetime_end']:
        raise ValidationError({'lesson_datetime_end': "End time must be later than start time."})
    return cleaned_data
```

In the same way, you could add a validator that the duration of the lesson isn't greater than a certain expected time interval (e.g. cannot be longer than 4 hours), by subtracting the two `datetime` fields and comparing them to `datetime.timedelta(hours=x)`.

You can also do it in your model, so assuming you have a `Lesson` model with fields `lesson_start` and `lesson_end`:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.lesson_start and self.lesson_end and self.lesson_start >= self.lesson_end:
        raise ValidationError({'lesson_end': "End time must be later than start time."})
```

Comment: I get the error, 'LessonForm' object has no attribute 'lesson_datetime_start' when I put it in my forms.py, and I get the error, '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType', when I put it in my models.py

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise this was for the form. Updated my answer for a ModelForm. Note I took a shortcut, you should check the values exist before accessing them in `cleaned_data` (`cleaned_data['lesson_datetime_start']` will raise a `KeyError` if no start date is submitted).

Comment: Thanks for the fix. The new error I get is clean() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: I was passing `self` to `super().clean()` which is obviously wrong. But that's basic python, should be obvious that I made a typo.